# Wget command : can't use -b and -P together

Tags: command-line, ftp, wget

I tried to download this link

```
ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/SRR615/008/SRR6156068/SRR6156068_1.fastq.gz
```

using `wget`.
I want to download in background and to a specific directory, so i use this command:

```
wget -b -P folder1/folder2 ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/SRR615/008/SRR6156068/SRR6156068_1.fastq.gz
```

But nothing is happening. My download didn't occur.

Comment: Have yuo also tried just downloading the file with -b after navigating to where you want the file stored yourself, to see if it downloads?  Note that `-b` is useful only if you have somewhere for error log output to go to, with the `-o` option so you can tail the log file to see what's going on with the download progress and such.

Comment: Yes. Only -b is worked. But when i used both -b and -P. When i run, it shows that my download will be in the background, and done in the folder. But when i check in the folder, no file at all

Answer (score 1):

Test your download with a known directory and filename first.

For example:

```
$ wget -b -P Downloads http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.14/linux-headers-4.14.0-041400_4.14.0-041400.201711122031_all.deb
Continuing in background, pid 11795.
Output will be written to ‘wget-log’.
```

This assumes your current directory is `/home/YOUR_NAME` and the subdirectory `Downloads` exists under it.

Check the log file `/home/YOUR_NAME/wget-log` for status messages.

After you know it works, then start experimenting with different folder names and web addresses. In your example `/home/YOUR_NAME/folder1/folder2` does not exist or the file you are trying to download doesn't exist.

---

#### Edit August 11, 2018

OP is getting this error:

> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset
>   by peer) in headers. Retrying.

Similar problem can be found here: [wget gets Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49543048/wget-gets-read-error-connection-reset-by-peer-in-headers).

The accept answer is to add the parameters `--auth-no-challenge --force-directories` to the end of the `wget` command:

```
$ wget -b -P Downloads http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.14/linux-headers-4.14.0-041400_4.14.0-041400.201711122031_all.deb --auth-no-challenge --force-directories
Continuing in background, pid 2176.
Output will be written to ‘wget-log.2’.
```

Comment: Yes. I've done in a known directory like this >>> wget -b -P PM ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/SRR615/008/SRR6156068/…                                   
only wget-log appears, not my wanted file. +.+ –

Comment: You can review `wget-log` for error messages. To verify your `wget` is working you can copy & paste my example into your terminal.

Comment: It didn't work even your link. I checked the wget file and it said that HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers. (same as my download files) Does it mean my wget has a problem??

Comment: I googled for error similar to yours and posted a revision to the answer.